# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ( for jest

Tags: javascript, testing, jestjs

After setting up some postcss and webpack, some of my jest tests failed. All failed for the same error. Very strange error, it seems that `Jest` can't even recognize arrow function rather than `async/await`.

```
FAIL  tests/backend/integration/models/threadsModel.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /Users/albertgao/codes/node/projectTalk/tests/backend/integration/models/threadsModel.test.js:115
        test('Should return empty list when no data could be fetched', async () => {
                                                                             ^
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token (

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/ScriptTransformer.js:289:17)
      at handle (node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:41:8)
      at process.<anonymous> (node_modules/worker-farm/lib/child/index.js:47:3)
      at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
```

The test is simple and passed before:

```
test('Should return empty list when no data could be fetched', async () => {
    const result = await ThreadModel.getThreads(threads[19], 5);
    expect(result).toHaveLength(0);
});
```

I tried:

- `--no-cache`
- delete `node_modules` and re-install all modules

Still got this error.

This is how I invoke the test:

```
"NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/.bin/jest --no-cache --config=configs/jest.config.json",
```

This is my `jest.config.js` in `./configs/` folder:

```
{
  "verbose": true,
  "rootDir": "../",
  "testPathIgnorePatterns": ["<rootDir>/node_modules/", "<rootDir>/tests/acceptance/", "<rootDir>/tests/coverageReport/", "<rootDir>/dist/"],
  "collectCoverage": false,
  "coverageDirectory": "tests/coverageReport",
  "collectCoverageFrom" : ["**/src/**"],
  "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": ["<rootDir>/node_modules/", "<rootDir>/configs/", "<rootDir>/src/config/appconfig.json", "<rootDir>/dist/"],
  "coverageReporters": ["text", "text-summary"]
}
```

This is my `.babelrc` in `./configs/` folder:

```
{
  "presets": [["env",{"modules":false}], "react"],
  "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"],
  "ignore": [
    "tests/",
    "dist/",
    "node_modules/",
    "src/backend/",
    "public"
  ]
}
```

I use the latest `Jest`

Any solution?

Answer (score 1):

since the **async arrow function** is supported in [ES2017](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-async_functions_async_arrow_functions). so you must config a javascript transpiler, e.g: [Babel](http://babeljs.io/).

```
 npm install --save-dev babel-jest regenerator-runtime babel-preset-stage-0
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-0"]
}
```

you can see the jest configuration as further at [Additional Configuration](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/getting-started.html#using-babel).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, tried but no, still the same error. Jest has a built-in babel-transformer and babel-jest has integrated long before.

Comment: @AlbertGao hi, see here there is an example: http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-async.html#async-await